# Неправильно выводит русские символы в char

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь сохранить русский символ в переменной unsigned char, но при сохранении символа 'а'(русского) выводит другой('р'). Проверял на разных русских символах и понял, что выводится буква на 16 порядков выше, то есть для 'б' выводится 'с', для 'в' - 'т' и т.д.

```
unsigned char a = 'в';
std::cout << a;
```

Думал уменьшить числовое значение char на 16, но выводит уже не буквы

```
unsigned char a = int('а') - 16;
```

Как мне все-таки вывести тот символ, который я ввел?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не подключена локализация.
Используйте `setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale> //Обязательно для функции setlocale()

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    unsigned char a = 'в';
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```